# Powershell script didn't see variable passed from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, parameter-passing

In my powershell script I have a variable `[switch]$showCurrnet = $false`, and it usage in the code is:

```
if($showCurrnet)
{
    //some code here
}
```

If I run this script in Powershell using this `./MyScript.ps1 -showCurrent`all works fine - script setup showCurrent flag to True and go inside `if` statemant.

But when I run this script from Jenkins pipeline like that:

```
stage('Run this script') {
            steps {
                script{
                echo "Some echo"
                bat 'powershell Path_to_my_script/MyScript.ps1 -showCurrent'
              } }
        }
```

script don't see `showCurrent` and don't go inside `if` statment.

What should I do to correctly pass this variable from Jenkins to my script?

Comment: `[switch]$showCurrnet = $false` and `if($showCurrnet)` should those not be `Current` instead of `Currnet`?

Comment: @Gerhard Right, I didn't see that. Thanks a lot!